# React Js + AWS Cloudfront + SaaS + SSL Certificates

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront, saas

This is the scenario I have in mind

- SaaS application
- Frontend built using React Js
- Hosted using S3 bucket + Cloudfront
- Customer domains pointing to this application using CNAME

Questions -

1. Can AWS certificate manager be used to issue SSL to all pointing domains ?
2. Is S3 + Cloudfront + AWS Certificate Manager the correct choice for such an application ?
3. What would be the cost of issuing SSL certificates in this scenarios. We are thinking of more than 100K customers

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this question? You can use s3 + Cloudfront + Lambda@edge till subdomain.yoursaas.com. Pointing client.com to your saas not very sure about that with AWS